# How do I check empty string in solidity?

Tags: string, blockchain, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

I'm learning solidity. I want to check if a memory string variable is a null, empty, or whitespaces.
I understand I have to check it like this:

```
bytes(_content).length > 0
```

However, this does now cover empty whitespace. What would be the best way to check for empty whitespace?
Or do you suggest that this check does not belong in s

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you convert "" to bytes you get `0x`

if you convert " " to bytes you get `0x20`

for each empty space, it adds another 20. for example 2 empty space

"  " is `0x2020`

empty string characters will always return "20" and as far as I know we could have slice operations with bytes array since solidity 6.0.0. For example

```
bytes test = '0xabcd'

test[2:5];  # 'abc'
```

Knowing this, if you have this

```
bytes whitespaces='0x20202020202020'
```

you could write a for loop, starting from 2 till the end,if the even index is 2 and odd index 0 that means you have only white spaces.

Comment: This is definitely a solution. Sounds like a good one. I will do this. But I do wonder if it's the most optimal solution in terms of performance and if its the cleanest solution in tems of code. But it sounds like its the only solution. Thanks @Yilmaz.

Comment: working with strings pains the neck in solidity.